# Basic limsup proof query

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Theorem 3.39 in Baby Rudin (3rd ed.) reads (where Rudin has earlier defined limsup as the supremum of the given set of subsequential limits)

> Given the power series $\sum c_n z^n$, put
> $\alpha=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$, $R=1/\alpha$ (if
> $\alpha=0$ then $R=+ \infty $ and if $\alpha=+ \infty$ then $R=0$).
> Then $\sum c_n z^n$ converges if $|z|<R$ and diverges if $|z|>R$.

Now the proof involves using the root test, and observing that, if $|z|<R$ so that $\frac{|z|}{R}<1$, then
$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|z^nc_n|}=|z|\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=|z|\alpha=\frac{|z|}{R}<1$$
and likewise for the $\frac{|z|}{R}>1$ case. My question is about proving the linearity of limsup, in particular the first equality above. I tried to proceed by contradiction:

Suppose there were some other supremum, $$\beta |z|=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|z^nc_n|}\neq|z|\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=|z|\alpha,$$ and in particular we would need $\beta |z|>|z|\alpha$ (else $\beta |z|$ not a supremum, for it's easy to see that $\alpha |z|$ is a subsequential limit). By an earlier theorem, we know that a limsup must be a subsequential limit itself, so for some indices $n_k$ (indexing the subsequence converging to $\beta |z|$), we have for every $\epsilon>0$ that there exists some $N$ such that $k\geq N$ implies (neglecting the case of z = 0, which always converges anyway)
$$||z|\sqrt[n_k]{|c_{n_k}|}|-\beta |z||<\epsilon|z| \implies|\sqrt[n_k]{|c_{n_k}|}|-\beta |<\epsilon$$
contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is the largest such subsequential limit.

Is this proof correct? It feels too flippant, although I suppose the statement it's proving isn't all that profound. If possible, and if my proof is not correct, please do not supply a proof that uses the other standard definition of limsup.

Answer (score 1):

I can agree with you proof, only the part where you say that $\beta|z|>\alpha|z|$ is a bit short compared to the rest.

Even though the question is answered, I suggest you proving this: *If $(b_n)_n$ is a sequence with elements in $\mathbb{C}$ and $a\neq 0$, then the sequence $(a\,b_n)_n$ converges if and only if the sequence $(b_n)_n$ converges. In that case the limit is $a\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n$.* (Prove it!)

Then, use it for your question setting $a=|z|$ and $b_k=\sqrt[n_k]{|c_{n_k}}|$, any subsequence.

This could give you much more clarity why you have linearity for the limsup (as well as liminf).